# Decision behind ROS2's Python tutorial switched from src layout to flat layout

Tags: python, ros2, packaging

As far as I can see, the entire tutorial suite of ROS2 (citing [Creating a package (docs.ros.org)](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package.html) to begin with) has switched from what is called "src layout" to "flat layout" (i.e. Python packages are directly placed at the top level directoryin a ROS/Ament package) regarding folder structuring in a package that hosts Python modules and even executables (Ref. ["src layout vs flat layout" (python.org)](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/)). Back in ROS1, Python binding tutorials were predominantly using "src layout" (i.e. Putting Python packages under a sub-folder called `src`) if I'm not mistaken.

Arguing about the decision is not my intention. I'm curious to see what was the decision behind the switch, as I haven't found anything. Personally I'm undecided if I choose either side, choice may depend on the type of package.

---

UPDATE-1: Just FYI, though this should be irrelevant from the "src/flat layout" decision, I found the current implementation of `ament(/colcon)` doesn't support "src layout" usecase well -- Using `ament_python_install_package(%PACKAGE_TOPDIR%)`, if I do `ament_python_install_package(src)` in order to let `ament` know where my Python modules/executables are in, then I get `src` installed, which is not a Python package I am making. The same cmake macro doesn't seem to support slash in the argument so passing `src/mypackage` errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that the rationale behind that exact change is likely lost to time. However, my intuition says this is likely a change related to one or more of:

- The removal of "devel" workspaces in ament. [Python documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/) notes that the "src layout" requires an installation step. With catkin, we had this going on, but ament only provides the --symlink-install option. Catkin had some really crazy CMake going on, and one of the main goals of Ament was to streamline things.
- ROS2 supports pure Python packages (with no CMakeLists.txt, just setup.py)
- Developer preferences. While there is some overlap in the team that created Catkin and the team that created Ament, the lead developers at inception of each project were different people.